# JavaScript Performance: access time of properties - 'this' vs 'global object' vs 'variable'

Tags: javascript

```
var globalObject = { x: 0 }; // some global object with 'x' property

function Object()
{
    this.x = 0;
}

Object.prototype.TestPerformance = function()
{
    var xVar = 0;
}
```

From the function `TestPerformance`, what is the order of access time for these properties/variables?

`this.x` vs `globalObject.x` vs `xVar`

Comment: Is `x` an own property in the `this.x` case?

Comment: Why do you want to know? (Just to give you a better answer)

Comment: What do you mean by "order of"? If you want numbers, you have to measure (on the exact implementation you are using)

Comment: One would expect `xVar` >= `this.x` >> `globalObject.x` but it depends a lot on the optimisations in effect

Comment: Note: the exact algorithms and data structures used for storing and accessing values is going to vary between implementations. You could come up with a theoretical model for all engines but that may not actually reflect what you see during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will be implementation dependent and is unknowable without looking at the engine source.

But best approximation:

```
this.x
```

O(1) time/complexity

```
globalObject.x
```

O(1) time/complexity

Assuming LexicalEnvironments are searched at compile time.

```
var xVar
```

O(1) time/complexity

Comment: LexicalEnvironments typically don't have to be searched, it can be statically established that the identifier `globalObject` refers to a global variable. Accessing and searching the global scope however is a different thing.

Comment: O(1) on average. Hash tables can be O(n) on the worst case.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain why the scope chain does not have to be searched for variable "globalObject" and instead can be statically determined?

Comment: @BenAston: It has to be searched once, for sure, but that's at the compilation of the function not every time when accessing the variable. (Unless you use `eval` or `with` in any of those scopes, which is exactly why they are evil)